# Keep control back color after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am changing back color of a Combo box when it has a value other than first value. (selectedindex = 0)

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server" onchange="ChangeBackColor(this);">
```

js to change the color;

```html
function ChangeBackColor(source) {
            if (source.selectedIndex > 0)
                source.style.backgroundColor = "LightGreen";
            else
                source.style.backgroundColor = "White";
        }
```

On that page there is a button, once click on that it reloads the page. I was able to preserve value using ViewStates.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn"
                                                    OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

But back color has gone back to default (white), I need to preserve that too. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the body tag:

```
<body onload="ChangeBackColor(document.getElementById(dropdownID))">
```

That should do what you want.

If you are using jQuery, do:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        ChangeBackColor(jQuery('#dropdownID'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If there is more than one combo on the page?

Comment: In that case you can give them a common css class name and use the following jQuery to get them:

`jQuery('.common_class_name').each(function(){ ChangeBackColor(this) });`

Answer (score 1):

in your page load event in the code behind, verify the selected value of your drop down list and set it to red on certain condition.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddl.selectedvalue != "whatever")
         ddl.BackColor = function_that_return_a_color();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `btnUpdate_Click` (or in `page_preRender`) handler add line.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ddlActiveColor",
   "ChangeBackColor(document.getElementById('" + ddlActive.ClientID + "'));", true);
```

If you do it in `page_preRender` then it is good idea to wrap this string into

```
if(page.IsPostBack({
   //ScriptManager...
}
```